# Vscode jupyter intellisense not showing doc for tensorflow keras

Tags: python

Vscode jupyter autocompletes, but doesn't show doc for `keras` fields

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras;
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

Even if I press <kbd>ctrl+shift+ space</kbd>, no doc shows to describe the functions and elements like `keras.layers.Flatten()`

Answer (score 0):

**Use** `import keras` to directly import keras

Don't do `tf.keras` or `from tensorflow import keras` or `keras = tf.keras`

Additionally,
enable `Extended kernel completion` in settings

- <kbd>Ctrl+,</kbd>
- Search `Extended kernel completion`
- Enable it